# How Can I Upload a Photo to Server in iPhone SDK?

Tags: ios, asp.net, iphone, web-services

The below is my method to upload a photo to the server. There are two parameters: `DeviceToken` and `ContentModel.ContentModel` that contains a dictionary. Inside 2 field there is `AlbumID` and `ContentPath`.

```
NSURL *rtfUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"AlertBody" withExtension:@".png"];
NSString *deviceToken = @"5FF2C5A6-3930-4102-99A7-A55107B4375C";
NSString *loStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:myUrl];

loStr = [loStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:loStr]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *postbody = [NSMutableData data];

[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n",@"deviceToken"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:deviceToken] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSDictionary *contentModel = @{
                            @"AlbumID" : @"0",
                            @"contentPath" : [rtfUrl absoluteString],
                            };
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n",@"contentModel"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",contentModel] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//Adding Image

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"AlertBody.png"], 0.3);
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"myfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",@"AlertBody.png"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; // filetype=\"image/png\";
[postbody appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


//Close form

[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];



//send data to server

[request setHTTPBody:postbody];

NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postbody length]];
[request addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
NSURLResponse *response = NULL;
NSError *requestError = NULL;
NSData *responseData1 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];

NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"response string ==%@;",responseString);
```

This is my code. What is the error in this? I am getting this response: `Source code **500** .web service is created using ASP.net.`

Please Help me. I am facing this problem a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code? It's tested and working fine. Hope it may help you to resolve your issue too.

```
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];

[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"]; 

[postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"yourImage.jpg\"\r\n", @"file"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[postData appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[postData appendData:imageData];

[postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```